# Allow Users to make clickable links in their posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink, sanitize

I have a Rails 3 app that lets users enter comments.  I want any valid URL in the comment to become a clickable link.  Is there a safe way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `auto_link` method to do this.

```
auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and
#     say hello to <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"
```

If you're on anything less than Rails 3.1, this is built in, otherwise you would need to use the [rails_autolink gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails_autolink)

Comment: Thanks!  This worked.  Do you know the reasoning behind removing it in Rails 3.1?  It seems so useful.

Comment: Apparently to allow for more frequent updates than the Rails release cycle allows. From the [commit on github](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/81cfbf4146d3c5a58054b64112b8ce196f2fc061#actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb): "Unfortunately this method is extremely difficult to secure correctly. Ensuring this method is bullet-proof takes a faster release cycle than we have for rails. That's why we moved it to a gem. Please use the gem if you need the functionality! :-)"